# Inserting and retrieving information from MySQL field in Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have a JSON field which I am experimenting with but I am having a bit of trouble with it.

I have added the following to my `Customer` model:

```
  protected $casts = [
    'billingConfig' => 'array'
  ];
```

And I updated a test field using the following in my controller:

```
  $customer->billingConfig = ['attachableType' => $request->attachmentsConfig];
  $customer->save();
```

After this, the following appears in my database:

```
{"attachableType": "combined"}
```

Now, when I go to grab this specific value through my blade:

```
{{$customer->billingConfig->attachableType}}
```

I get "Trying to get property 'attachableType' of non-object"

But when I use the below:

```
{{$customer->billingConfig['attachableType']}}
```

I get the "combined" value I was looking for.

I was using this guide: https://www.qcode.in/use-mysql-json-field-in-laravel/, and I guess I wanted to make sure I was doing everything right and their method was wrong or I had goofed up somewhere.

Comment: when you receive the row from the database with Eloquent, you cast the billingConfig field to be an array, not an object. for that when you tried to access to the attachableType, you get an error because billingConfig it's array not object

Answer (score 0):

JSON data fields are being read as an array, which you can not call a property for, that's what I believe the reason for the error you got when called

```
{{$customer->billingConfig->attachableType}}
```

because it's an array, not a data object (like the case in javascript).

Thanks for sharing.